# Express Js infinitely endpoint called

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I have a backend route at mainScript in expressJS. I spawn a process from it. It takes some time to run the script. But after some time the express server calls the end point again on it's own and keeps doing that infinitely.

```js
app.get('/mainScript',function(req,res){
        console.log("mainScript API End Point Reached")
        const runScript = spawn('python3',['./demo.py'])
        let error_message = ""
        let stdout_message = ""
        runScript.stdout.on('data', function(data){
                console.log(`stdout:${data}`)
                stdout_message += data
        })
        runScript.stderr.on('data',function(data){
                console.log(`stderr:${data}`)
                error_message += data
        })
        runScript.on('close',function(code){
                console.log(`Child process exited with code : ${code}`)
                if(code == 0){
                        console.log("HI ERROR CODE = 0")
                        res.status(200)
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({"stdout_logs":stdout_message,
                                "Message" : 'Main Script Ran successfully'
                }))
                }else{
                        res.status(400)
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({"stderr_logs":error_message,
                                "Message" : "There was error on running the main script"
                }))
                }
        })
})
```

What can be the reason for this ??

Comment: what does it mean to "call the end point again on it's own"?  what function is being called and what are the effects?

Comment: So the console.log("mainScript API End Point Reached") is seen again and again on the output and the process is spawned again and again